# Points in linear general position and automorphisms

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry, projective-space

Let $S=\{p_1,\ldots,p_n\}\subset\mathbb{P}^2$ be a subset of points of the projective plane. Assume that there exists a subset $A\subseteq S$ of five points in linear general position (meaning that no three of these 5 points lie on the same line). Assume that there is an automorphism $\phi$ of $\mathbb{P}^2$ mapping $S$ to itself. May we conclude that then $\phi$ must be the identity?

Comment: When you say $\phi$ takes $S$ to itself, do you mean $\phi$ permutes elements of $S$ or identity on $S$? If the former, the answer is clearly false.

Comment: I mean that it permutes de points of $S$. I am thinking that I can map $4$ points in $4$ points but then I can not move the fifth point.

Comment: In other words I am asking wheter a permutation of more that $5$ points (in general position) can be realized by a linear automorphism of $\mathbb{P}^2$.

Comment: Take five such points $A=\{p_1,\ldots, p_5\}$ and let $\phi$ be a non-trivial involution. Then take $S=A\cup\phi(A)$.